# How do I configure my server to use a fixie static IP?

Tags: heroku, whitelist, static-ip-address

I have sent a GET request using clash of clans API and axios and provided the authentication for it to work locally however it doesn't work when deployed as heroku uses dynamic Ip addresses.

I am looking to use static Ip addresses which Heroku will use to authorize my api request. I have chosen fixie however I dont think my server is actually using the static IP as when navigate to the endpoint, the page fails and the network tab shows a remote connection from what seems to be a heroku IP address. Essentially I need to whitelist an Ip.

Here is my code:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const axios = require("axios");
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');
const fixieUrl = url.parse(process.env.FIXIE_URL);
const requestUrl = url.parse('https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/players/%232889v22uq');
// const URL = "https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/players/%232889v22uq";

const options = {
  headers: {
    Host: requestUrl.host,
    'Proxy-Authorization': `Basic ${Buffer.from(fixieUrl.auth).toString('base64')}`,
    "Authorization": `Bearer ${process.env.API_TOKEN}`
  },
  host: fixieUrl.hostname,
  port: fixieUrl.port,
  path: requestUrl.href,
};

app.get("/api", (req, res) => {

  const clashReq = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(requestUrl, options);

      const {
        name,
        townHallLevel,
        trophies,
        bestTrophies,
        builderHallLevel,
        league: {
          name: leagueName,
          iconUrls: { medium: mediumIcon },
        },
        legendStatistics: {
          previousSeason: { trophies: previousTrophies},
          bestSeason: { trophies: bestSeasonTrophies},
          currentSeason: { trophies: currentTrophies},
        },
      } = response.data;
      
      res.json({
          name,
          townHallLevel,
          trophies,
          bestTrophies,
          builderHallLevel,
          leagueName,
          mediumIcon,
          previousTrophies,
          bestSeasonTrophies,
          currentTrophies
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  clashReq();
 

  console.log(res.statusCode);
  
});



if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/client/build")));
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/client/build", "index.html"));
  });
}

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3001, () => {
  console.log(`Server running`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Axios can make HTTPS requests over a proxy out of the box. You just need to provide a `proxy` configuration object in `options`:

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const url = require('url');
const fixieUrl = url.parse(process.env.FIXIE_URL);
const fixieAuth = fixieUrl.auth.split(':');

axios.get('https://example.com', {
  proxy: {
    protocol: 'http',
    host: fixieUrl.hostname,
    port: fixieUrl.port,
    auth: {username: fixieAuth[0], password: fixieAuth[1]}
  }
}).then(response => {
  console.log(response.status);
});
```

If you do this, you can remove the `Proxy-Authorization` and `Host` headers, as well as the explicit `host`, `port`, and and `path` options.

What Axios is doing under the hood is that it makes a `CONNECT` request to Fixie to open an [HTTP tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel) to the remote, and the request to the remote is then made over that tunnel. This is different than how an HTTP request is proxied, but Axios abstracts that difference away.